# JS fetch API: How to fetch content from multiple files with one async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

I would like to fetch data from multiple files with a single async function. Currently my code is like this:

```
const fetchExternalData = async() => {
   const resp1 = await fetch('file1.txt');
   const resp2 = await fetch('file2.txt');
   return resp1.text(); // How could I return the content from file2.txt as well?
}

fetchExternalData().then((response) => {
  console.log(response); // Data from file1.txt
  // How could I access the data from file2.txt?
}
```

This way, I can work with the data from the first file, but how could I access the data from more files this way? Hope the question is understandable. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Return an array of results: `return [resp1.text() , resp2.text()]` then use `Promise.all()` to wait on them

Comment: @slebetman dont answer questions in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could go about this using `Promise.all`:

```js
const fetchExternalData = () => {
  return Promise.all([
    fetch("file1.txt"),
    fetch("file2.txt")
  ])
  .then(
    results => Promise.all(
      results.map(result => result.text())
    )
  )
}
```

Then, when calling your `fetchExternalData` function, you will get an array of items with data from both of your files:

```js
fetchExternalData().then(
  (response) => {
    // [file1data, file2data]
  }
)
```

Here's an example:

```js
const fetchExternalData = () => {
  return Promise.all([
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"),
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2")
  ]).then(results => {
    return Promise.all(results.map(result => result.json()));
  });
};

fetchExternalData()
  .then(result => {
    // console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Alternatively, if you'd want to return an `object` instead of an `array`, you could do something like the following:

```js
const fetchExternalData = items => {
  return Promise.all(
    items.map(item =>
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${item.id}`)
    )
  )
  .then(
    responses => Promise.all(
      responses.map(response => response.json())
    )
  )
  // use `Array.reduce` to map your responses to appropriate keys
  .then(results =>
    results.reduce((acc, result, idx) => {
      const key = items[idx].key;
      
      // use destructing assignment to add 
      // a new key/value pair to the final object
      return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: result
      };
    }, {})
  );
};

fetchExternalData([
  { id: 1, key: "todo1" }, 
  { id: 2, key: "todo2" }
])
  .then(result => {
    console.log("result", result);
    console.log('todo1', result["todo1"]);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

References:

- [Promise.all - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Array.reduce - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Destructing assignment - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, I can access the result array with ```result[0]```. Is there a way to add keys to the result array, so I could access it with ```result['key1']```?

Comment: @martin-hinze so you mean returning an object? See the edit

Comment: @martin-hinze and keys no, but you could just return an `object` like in my second example, or you could return an array of objects with the key that you want and you'd have to use the `Array.find` method to find the appropriate item, you wouldn't be able to do `result["key1"]` like you want it though

Comment: Thank you for the edit, this is more than I was hoping for. I will study your code meticulously and learn a lot from it!

Comment: @martin-hinze let me know if there are any questions or if there's a part that you don't understand, I will edit the question and provide more comments

Answer (score 1):

return multiple values by putting it in an object. like this:

```
const fetchExternalData = async() => {
   const resp1 = await fetch('file1.txt');
   const resp2 = await fetch('file2.txt');
   return ({res1: resp1.text(), res2: resp2.text()});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! I chose the answer from @goto1, because it is more flexible, but your's is helpful, too!

Comment: By the way, `resp1.text()` will return a `Promise`, so you'd need to do something like `obj.rest1.then(...)` to get the value that this `Promise` resolves with.